# PHP download doesn't work properly

Tags: php

I just wanted to make some kind of "download service" but it isn't working.

Whole download.php:

```
<?php
    include "utils/config.php";
    include "utils/utils.php";

    if($isLoggedIn && isset($_POST['id']) && hasProduct($userid,$_POST['id'])){

        $ID = $_POST['id'];
        $pdata = getProduct($ID);
        $file = $pdata['file'];
        $name = $pdata['dlfile'];
        $mime = $pdata['file_mime_type'];

        #echo $file."<br>".$name."<br>".$mime;

        /**
         * $file = "assets/files/151708025047541"
         * $name = "API.jar"
         * $mime = "application/java-archive"
         */

        download($file,$name,$mime); // <-- wouldn't work
        #download("assets/files/151708025047541","API.jar","application/java-archive"); // <-- wouldn't work
    }
    #download("assets/files/151708025047541","API.jar","application/java-archive"); // <-- would work fine
?>
```

Function "download" in utils.php:

```
function download($f_location, $f_name, $type){
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: '.$type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($f_location));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($f_name).'"');
    ob_clean();
    readfile($f_location);
}
```

The only thing "config.php" contains are some variables.
The only thing "utils.php" contains are some functions and it's connecting to the database (which is needed for $isLoggedIn, hasProduct (...) and getProduct (...).

The download itself is wokring, but it wants to download a file with zero content and with the name "download.php".
At my comments you see, if I try the same function (with static args) outside the if-block the download works fine. But if I try to use function (with static args) inside the if-block it will give me the same problem.

Funny thing is that the same function still worked a few months ago.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I download these files dynamic with an authorization-check (as I have already tried)?

I hope you understand my problem:)

Comment: Just a note... From php manual: _The output buffer must be started by `ob_start()` with `PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE` flag. Otherwise `ob_clean()` will not work._

Comment: I tested your codes it works for me maybe there's an issue on your data passing.

Comment: You're right. I tested it with Firefox and it's working! So with Chrome it isn't working, i just have to find the issue in Chrome ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Download-Manager add-on was trying to catch the download..

Just added an exception/disabled the add-on and now it's working!